# PHP image upload upside down (apparently not an exif issue)

Tags: php, upload, image-uploading, exif

I'm uploading [this picture](https://www.lucapennisi.com/repository/test.jpg) with PHP (from a Windows 10 PC) on a Linux server. After the upload is finished, the file is saved on the server, but upside down! I have this issue with the above linked image only.

I have tried to adjust the exif rotation following several tutorials, none of them worked.

Here's the code that I'm using:

```
//File name
$filename = $_FILES['files']['name'][$i];
$filename_tmp = $_FILES['files']['tmp_name'][$i];

//Extension
$ext = pathinfo($filename, PATHINFO_EXTENSION);

////////////////////////////////////////////////
//resize
////////////////////////////////////////////////

$size = getimagesize($filename_tmp);
$ratio = $size[0]/$size[1]; 
if( $ratio > 1) {
    $width = 1200;
    $height = 1200/$ratio;
}
else {
    $width = 1200*$ratio;
    $height = 1200;
}
$src = imagecreatefromstring(file_get_contents($filename_tmp));
$dst = imagecreatetruecolor($width,$height);
imagecopyresampled($dst,$src,0,0,0,0,$width,$height,$size[0],$size[1]);
imagedestroy($src);
imagejpeg($dst,$directory.'/f-'.$i.'.'.$ext,50); // adjust format as needed

////////////////////////////////////////////////
//correct orientation
////////////////////////////////////////////////

// read EXIF header from uploaded file
$exif = exif_read_data($directory.'/f-'.$i.'.'.$ext);

// fix the Orientation if EXIF data exists
if (!empty($exif['Orientation'])) {
  switch ($exif['Orientation']) {
    case 8:
      $command = 'mogrify -rotate "90" -auto-orient ' . $directory.'/f-'.$i.'.'.$ext;
      exec("$command");
      break;
    case 3:
      $command = 'mogrify -rotate "180" -auto-orient ' . $directory.'/f-'.$i.'.'.$ext;
      exec("$command");
      break;
    case 6:
      $command = 'mogrify -rotate "-90" -auto-orient ' . $directory.'/f-'.$i.'.'.$ext;
      exec("$command");
      break;
  }
}

imagejpeg($dst,$directory.'/preview/f-'.$i.'.'.$ext.'.jpg',20); //thumbnail
imagedestroy($dst);
```

Comment: Just because your mogrify commands didn't have any effect, doesn't mean you have ruled out an EXIF issue. You're not even checking that the commands were executed successfully. You should confirm the new value of Orientation before coming to that conclusion.